# ZXing Barcodescanner with Phonegap and Windows 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, cordova, zxing, barcode-scanner

I need to integrate the ZXing barcode scanning library with a Windows 8 app(port from iOS/Android). I did successfuly use the [Windows (7) Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/WindowsPhone/BarcodeScanner/deploy) however this plugin only supports QR codes and not "Regular Barcodes" (UPC-A) format.

This plugin uses the 1.7 version of zxing library I need to either upgrade it to the latest (2.2) which I believe supports the UPC-A format or go with the [.NET Port](http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/)

Either way I havent figured out how as I am no .NET developer and havent found any tutorials how to integrate the ZXing library with Phonegap, I know it can be done just not how.

A step by step guild would be best if you have any links about this.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, how did you integrate this into Windows 8? I thought the Phonegap Windows 8 project was purely a JS one?